Moon observations at different places on the earth
How does look like the rising then attaining the maximum altitude and then finally setting of the moon when seen from either of the poles of the earth.

From the poles of the Earth the moon, sun and stars complete their daily motion in a circle centred directly overhead.  This means that that rising and setting is much much slower.
For the stars, (which are "fixed") there is no rising and setting. They just move in circles around the sky.  Any stars which are south of the equator never rise; any stars which are north of the equator never set.
For the sun, the rising and setting is annual.  The sun rises in the spring and sets in the autumn.  During the summer, the sun is above the horizon all day, during the winter it never rises.
For the moon the motion is monthly. In winter the full moon is above the horizon at all times, but as the moon wanes and becomes a crescent it gets lower in the sky and sets over the course of the month.  In the summer the moon is below the horizon when it is full and generally hard to see as a crescent the sun is above the horizon for 24 hours.

By the way,  I have no idea what implications this has for those who follow a lunar calendar, and live at the poles.
